# SQL select from first table according to list of values from second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table "person" like this

```
  id  |  firstName  |  lastName  |  ...
-----------------------------------------
  1   | Bill        | Gates      |
  2   | Steve       | Jobs       |
  3   | Linus       | Torvalds   |
```

and second table "virtue" like this

```
  id  | person_id | v_key    | v_value
---------------------------------------------
  1   | 1         | OS       | Windows Mobile
  2   | 1         | Company  | Microsoft
  3   | 2         | OS       | iOS
  4   | 2         | Company  | Apple
```

I could count virtues for all persons like this

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName, count(b.v_key)
  from person a
  left join virtue b on b.person_id = a.id
  group by a.firstName, a.lastName
```

Now I need to select all persons from first table who have given list of virtues like "OS"="iOS", "Company"="Apple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to fetch persons who have all virtues you gave, then you can use `group by` and filter on `count`:

```
with cte_given_list as (
    select *
    from (values ('OS', 'iOS'), ('Company', 'Apple')) as c(v_key, v_value)
)
select
    p.firstName, p.lastName
from cte_given_list as c
    inner join virtue as v on v.v_key = c.v_key and v.v_value = c.v_value
    inner join person as p on p.id = v.person_id
group by p.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from cte_given_list as t)
```

Note that here I'm grouping by id but selecting names. It's possible in PostgreSQL if id is primary key in person table.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/02530/1)</kbd>**

Comment: basically, you just have to check if your table matches all rows in the given list, so count of records in the recordset should be equal count of records in the given list, hence having

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, the only extra criteria is the OS=IOS and Company=Apple, and you're not interested in the other options. In that case, you could use something like this:

> select a.firstName, a.lastName 
>   from person a
>   left join virtue b on b.person_id = a.id 
>   AND (b.v_key = 'OS' AND b.v_value = 'iOS') OR (b.v_key = 'Company' AND b.v_value = 'Apple')
>   group by a.firstName, a.lastName

If you need to pull them OS by OS or company by company, you could consider supplying them as parameters.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, but (b.v_key = 'OS' AND b.v_value = 'iOS') AND (b.v_key = 'Company' AND b.v_value = 'Apple') will produce zero result because b.v_key can't be 'OS' and 'Company' at the same time

Comment: @n00bot - I changed it to an OR instead

Comment: Now we will get ALL persons with "OS"="iOS" AND all persons with "Company"="Apple", but I need to find only those who have "iOS" and "Apple" (both)